# Difficulty in replacing null values of a column in a dataframe using python pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

`df1 = df.fillna(1000383613, inplace = True).head(7)`  #df1 is updated dataframe

when I run the code above is giving the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fillna'

Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `df` is `None`, but we'd need to see the (previous) code that caused this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `inplace=True` keyword argument to assign the filled dataframe to a new variable.

The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) specify:

> **inplace**: bool, default False
>
> If True, fill in-place. Note: this will modify any other views on this object (e.g., a no-copy slice for a column in a DataFrame).

**EDIT**: if `df` is `None` (as noted by @BigBen's comment), then there might be a unneeded `inplace=True` further up in the code. To run `df.fillna(...)`, `df` must be of type `pd.Series` or `pd.DataFrame`.
.